# Huawei, Honor phones battery optimisation, Foreground Service

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager, huawei-mobile-services

This question may looks very broad but I will try to sum up as short I could do.

So I am replicating a sample app on Play store [Multi Timer Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.catfantom.multitimerfree&hl=en)

App is for setting Multiple Timers.

I have almost completed the app. but I am facing some issues of battery optimization and Alarm Manager specifically Huawai and Honor (china Andorid OS). My Foreground service stops working after some time.

**Question:**
Sample app mentioned above works very fantastic even without battery optimization whitelist. What could be the solution for this?

I have almost tries everything mentioned in links follows. but no luck

[Doze mode - do foreground services continue to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866806/doze-mode-do-foreground-services-continue-to-run)

[How to handle background services in ANDROID O?](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-to-handle-background-services-in-android-o-f96783e65268)

[How to turn off battery optimization on Huawei devices](https://support.doubletwist.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001504071-How-to-turn-off-battery-optimization-on-Huawei-devices)

[How to turn off battery optimization on the Huawei devices](http://nine-faq.9folders.com/articles/16876-how-to-turn-off-battery-optimization-on-the-huawei-devices)

[How to turn off battery optimization on Huawei devices](https://help.safelagoon.com/en/articles/3203458-how-to-turn-off-battery-optimization-on-huawei-devices)

[Don't kill my app!](https://dontkillmyapp.com/huawei)

[Huawei device killing my foreground service, even with dontkillmyapp.com's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56883074/huawei-device-killing-my-foreground-service-even-with-dontkillmyapp-coms-solut/56935425)

[Keep the device awake](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#cpu)

[Optimize for Doze and App Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)

[Android M startActivity battery optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41596509/android-m-startactivity-battery-optimization)

[Battery optimizations (wakelocks) on Huawei EMUI 4.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954822/battery-optimizations-wakelocks-on-huawei-emui-4-0)

[service killed when app cloes just in huawei device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48559465/service-killed-when-app-cloes-just-in-huawei-device)

[Oreo (8.1) cannot start activity on lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48404795/oreo-8-1-cannot-start-activity-on-lock-screen)

[Creating a never ending background service in Android > 7](https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android-gt-7)

[How does doze mode affect background/foreground services, with/without partial/full wakelocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869201/how-does-doze-mode-affect-background-foreground-services-with-without-partial-f)

[What to do if alarms or sleep tracking don’t work?](https://sleep.urbandroid.org/documentation/faq/alarms-sleep-tracking-dont-work/#huawei)

> Sample Code, When pressed device lock/unlock button, I want a simple
>   TOAST to be shown when SCREEN_ON broadcast is received. This works
>   fine for some time.
>
> But in Huawei device => After killing the app by swipe -> after a 1 -
>   2 minutes my toast will stop working.

```
package com.demo.forgroundservicedemo

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import android.os.Build
import android.app.*
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.graphics.Color
import android.util.Log
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import android.os.SystemClock
import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.widget.Toast


class ForegroundService : Service() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        Log.e("ForegroundService", "onCreate called")
        super.onCreate()
    }

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun startMyOwnForeground() {
    val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = CONST.CHANNELID
    val channelName = CONST.channelName
    val chan = NotificationChannel(
        NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
        channelName,
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
    )
    chan.lightColor = Color.BLUE
    chan.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
    val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    manager.createNotificationChannel(chan)

    val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)

    notificationIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

    val intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this, 0,
        notificationIntent, 0
    )

    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(intent)
    val notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(CONST.serviceTitle)
        .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
        .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .build()

    notification.flags = notification.flags or Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
    startForeground(2, notification)
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    Log.e("ForegroundService", "onStartCommand called")
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Log.e("SDK_INT", ">= Build.VERSION_CODES.O")
        startMyOwnForeground()
    } else {
        startForeground(1, Notification())
    }

    registerBroadcastReceiver()
    return START_STICKY
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    Log.e("ForegroundService", "onDestroy called")
    super.onDestroy()
}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}

private var mPowerKeyReceiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null

private fun registerBroadcastReceiver() {

    Log.e("registerBroadcast", "called")
    val theFilter = IntentFilter()
    /** System Defined Broadcast  */
    theFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
    //theFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)

    mPowerKeyReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

            Log.e("onReceive", "onReceive called")
            val strAction = intent!!.action

            if (strAction == Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "SCREEN ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }

    applicationContext.registerReceiver(mPowerKeyReceiver, theFilter)
}

private fun unregisterReceiver() {
    val apiLevel = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT

    if (apiLevel >= 7) {
        try {
            applicationContext.unregisterReceiver(mPowerKeyReceiver)
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            mPowerKeyReceiver = null
        }

    } else {
        applicationContext.unregisterReceiver(mPowerKeyReceiver)
        mPowerKeyReceiver = null
    }
}

override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
    Log.e("onTaskRemoved", "onTaskRemoved called")
    unregisterReceiver()

    val restartService = Intent(
        applicationContext,
        this.javaClass
    )
    restartService.setPackage(packageName)
    val restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
        applicationContext, 1, restartService,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
    )
    val alarmService =
        applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    alarmService.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
        AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 500,
        restartServicePI
    )
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share details of the implementation? Maybe you have missed something

Comment: @leonardkraemer sample code added. Its my actual code. but service code is same.

Comment: @QadirHussain is your issue solved? I am also facing similar problem

Comment: @Kameswari no bro. not yet

Comment: "This works fine for some time" How long is some time? I have a similar problem. My foreground service or maybe broadcast receiver stoped after about 20days or 1 month. Honor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you don't have `setRepeating` when scheduling an alarm?

I'm doing the same thing basically (updating the widget when the screen is ON), and I'm doing it like this:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, interval, pendingIntent)
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. did you try your code on Huawei Devices?

Comment: I haven't tried it on any Huawei device, but have it like this for a while now in production and no one reported the issue yet. Your code example only uses setExactAndAllowWhileIdle

Answer (score 0):

Emui 5.0 / 5. X: Settings > Application Management > Settings > special access rights Zhidao > ignore battery optimization > application, set to allow.
Emui 8.0 / 8. X: Settings > apps and notifications > app Management > Settings > special access > ignore battery optimization > app, set to allow

Comment: you can also get it as a permission from the user. IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS_REQUEST